# Suggestions for implementing a countdown in Node.JS

Tags: node.js

I'm learning node.JS and creating a connected Nerf gun as my learning project. When arming the gun, I would like to display a 10 second countdown on the LCD. I thought the below code would work, but it completes the countdown immediately with zero delay. Any suggestions?

```
function countdown(count){
  lcd.cursor(1,0);  
  lcd.print("ARMING IN " + count);
  count = count - 1;
  if(count > 0){        
    setTimeout(countdown(count), 1000);     
  }  
}
```

Comment: `setTimeout(() => countdown(count), 1000);` don't call the function immediately, but after a second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setTimeout() accepts a function to execute as its first argument and the millisecond delay defined as a number as the second argument. Additional arguments may also be included and these will be passed on to the function. Here is an example of this and a link to the description

```
setTimeout(countdown, 1000, count);
```

https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/timers-in-node/